# MySql looping inside a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

If I had a set of numbers stored in a table column like say `1,60,71` how can I get my sql to loop through that set of numbers using while or some other method inside a stored procedure?

I like to do

```
Loop throught 1,60 and 71
Update row where id = 1,60 and 71 with my data.
```

I hope you get the idea.

Edit:
**Table before update**

```
"id"    "total" "vals"
"1"     "0"     ""
"2"     "0"     ""
"3"     "0"     ""
"4"     "0"     "1,2,3"
```

**After Update**

```
"id"    "total" "vals"
"1"     "1"     ""
"2"     "1"     ""
"3"     "2"     ""
"4"     "0"     "1,2,3"
```

Since `vals` of `id 4` are `1,2,3` - rows with id 1,2,3 have been update by `+1`

The only problem is going thru each of the values in that vals string, and updating the corresponding row by +1

Comment: What is the actual update statement. Maybe you can do it in 1 step

Comment: Put a JOIN in the UPDATE statement.

Comment: @juergend 1,60,70 is stored as a string in the table ( I dont my changing it if it makes things easier). The actual update is: update table set total = total+1 where id = 1 and then all the other numbers in that string (60 then 70)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JOIN, not a loop:

```
UPDATE Table t1
JOIN Table t2
ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.id, t2.vals)
SET t1.total = t1.total  + 1
WHERE t2.id = 4
```

Comment: That problem is, that `1,60,71` is stored as a string in a column and are not separate rows.

Comment: I've revised my answer to use FIND_IN_SET

Comment: Egads! Who even thought it was this simple. I wrote stored procedures etc. etc.